# Resetting path variables Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am setting up swipe navigation for use with jquery mobile. I create a function that sets the next and back urls based on a navigation ul (passed into the function with a variable).

The function works great on initial load and when using window.location instead of the proper $.mobile.changePage ajax call. Is there a way to reset the variables of this function after each ajax page load so that it has the proper paths.

I am calling this inside the data-role="page" element on each page, but the variables are still being passed on load.

```
function swipeNav(targetList){
        /* Setup Nav array - links and IDs */
        var navIDs = new Array();
        var navLinks = new Array();
        var nextPage = 0;
        var pervPage = 0;

        /* Setup Nav array with links and ids */
        $(targetList + ' li').each(function(){
          navIDs.push($(this).find('a').attr('id'));
          navLinks.push($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
        });

        /* Get current nav item based on location path */
        var currentURL = window.location.pathname;
        var htmlPage = currentURL.split('/');

        var currentPage = $.inArray(htmlPage[htmlPage.length-1], navLinks);
        if(currentURL == "/"){
            currentPage = 0;
            }

        /* Get number of nav items, prepare for navigation loop */
        var navLoop = navLinks.length;

        /* Sets next & prev page number based on current URL path */
        nextPage = currentPage + 1;
        prevPage = currentPage - 1;

        /* Add swipe support for navigation / based on navigation items */
        $('body').live('swipeleft swiperight',function(event){
            if (event.type == "swipeleft") {
                if(nextPage == navLoop){ $.mobile.changePage(navLinks[0]); }
                else{ $.mobile.changePage(navLinks[nextPage]); }    /* If last page of nav, loop to page 1 */
             }
             if (event.type == "swiperight") {
                if(prevPage < 0){ $.mobile.changePage(navLinks[navLoop - 1]); }
                else{ $.mobile.changePage(navLinks[prevPage]); } /* If first page of nav, loop to last page */
             }
        });
    }
```

Here is the call for this function within each page

```
<div id="page-load" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/swipenav.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
swipeNav('ul.nav-links');      
});
</script>
```